# JS: mouseOver function: new state doesn't pick up css from the old state

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, mouseover

I'd like to use the mouseOver/mouseOut function in JS to change the colour of an icon.

The icon is white but I'd like it to turn turquoise upon hover over and then back to white when the mouse moves away from the icon.

In my file I have 3 docs:

```
.html
.css
.js
```

and 2 images:

skull.png (white icon)
skull2.png (turquoise icon)

Here is my html:

```
 <div id='skull'>
   <a href="#" onmouseover="mouseOver()" onmouseout="mouseOut()">
   <img class="icon" src="skull.png" alt="skull"/></a>
 </div>
```

Here is my css for the 'icon' class:

```
.icon {
    margin: 0 25px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}
```

And the js for the function:

```
function mouseOver() {
document.getElementById("skull").innerHTML = '<img src="skull2.png" />';
}
function mouseOut() {
document.getElementById("skull").innerHTML = '<img src="skull.png" />';
}
```

I'm having two issues:

1. The first is that when I hover over the white skull, the skull whilst turning turquoise does not pick up the dimensions set out by the "icon" class. The dimensions are the size of the .png rather. I'd like them the size of skull.png as specified in the css. Not sure how this works?
2. When you hover off the turquoise skull, the icon does not return to white

Here is a video to show what I mean a little more: https://www.screenmailer.com/v/I5amMjkBaaeLtLU

(Apologies I'm pretty new to programming)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you do not have to change the entire inner HTML, and you could go about it by changing only the image src attribute. This way you can get the image by ID only once and not every time that the function is called.

```js
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');

img.onmouseout = function () {
   this.src = 'http://www.facetheforce.today/darthvader/200/200';
};

img.onmouseover = function () {
   this.src = 'http://www.facetheforce.today/c3po-alt/200/200';
};
```

```html
<img id="myImg" src="http://www.facetheforce.today/darthvader/200/200"/>
```

Another way you can go about it is by using CSS hover and background image.
For example:

```css
#bg-image {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
  background: url("http://www.facetheforce.today/darthvader/200/200");
}

#bg-image:hover {
  background: url("http://www.facetheforce.today/c3po-alt/200/200");
}
```

```html
<div id="bg-image"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function mouseOver() {
    document.getElementById("skull").innerHTML = '<a href="#" onmouseover="mouseOver()" onmouseout="mouseOut()"><img src="skull2.png" class="icon" alt="skull" />';
}
function mouseOut() { 
    document.getElementById("skull").innerHTML = '<a href="#" onmouseover="mouseOver()" onmouseout="mouseOut()"><img src="skull.png" class="icon" alt="skull" />';
}
```

You are not setting the img class as `.icon`. Also, your areremoving the anchor from your div in the first `mouseOver` call because you are replacing it's content by `<img src="skull2.png" />`

This must solve your two problems, but there's a better way to do this.

Add an `id` to your image, then get in the functions and change only the images's `src` attribute.